# Incorrect GMT time

Tags: time, timezone

My clock shows wrong time for GMT!

[image: Wrong GMT]

My local time is correct (Tehran, IRAN = GMT +3:30), but as it's clear from the above screenshot, GMT (Greenwich) is 1 hour behind according to Google!

The UTC and Pacific times are correct (checked with Google).

Note that "Time & Date" settings are set to "Automatically from the Internet".

Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Are you taking into account that the local time in Greenwich will currently be BST (British Summer Time), which is 1hr ahead of GMT?

Comment: It's not clear what the entry "Greenwich" means, under the callender - it could be GMT, or current time at Greenwich, which would be BST.

Comment: @steeldriver To add new locations in the "Time & Date" settings, you just type the name of the location, then select the desired item from the popup list. And there is only one "Greenwich, UK" in the list.

Comment: can you type "date ; date -u" in a terminal and show the results ?

Comment: @Archemar Here is the output:
`Tue Sep  9 16:52:16 IRDT 2014` 
`Tue Sep  9 12:22:16 UTC 2014`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use UTC instead of GMT

The time entry "Greenwich" under the calender is confusing.

One could obviously think of **GMT** - **Greenwich Mean Time**, which is used very often.

But it could also be just the plain current time at the location Greenwich. That would be BST - British Summer Time.

The entry **UTC** is less ambiguous - and comparing at that entry, "**Greenwich**" can only be Greenwich local time, as [**GMT** and **UTC** are the same, roughly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

**GMT** is not available as time zone at all. **UTC** should be used instead. That makes sense because **GMT** does not have a precise definition, which **UTC** does have.

Comment: Well there is no entry for "GMT" in the "Time & Date" list. There is only one "Greenwich, UK" which I selected, assuming that it's GMT. If this is not GMT, then how can I have a GMT entry?

Comment: See my edit - it's UTC; It's pretty complicated why there are both, really.

Comment: Oh! So the point is `UTC == GMT` ... And that's why there's no GMT in the list! I guess my problem is solved. The solution is: Just look at UTC and forget about Greenwich  `;)`

Comment: Yes, UTC == GMT - except that it's not allways really clear what GMT is, and UTC is absolutely clear.